# Python 2.7.10, unsupported operand type(s) error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a numeric solver in python. One of the conditions in the code is:

```
elif bounds != None and (targetfunction(bounds[0])-target)*(targetfunction(bounds[1])-target) > 0:
```

This was working fine a moment ago and now all of a sudden I am getting this error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Any ideas as to what's going on? The check is for is for when the input is not '`None`', the code checks if the solution exists in the bounds specified.

Comment: `targetfunction` is retuning `None`, which is what happens when it doesn't reach a `return` statement at all.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but the code post 'and' is only evaluated if the first part is true? If that's the case, then the function won't return None.

Comment: Then the `targetfunction` function almost certainly has a bug in it. If you'd posted the source, we could help you find it.

Comment: Its working fine now, targetfunction returned a tuple and I hadn't considered that, but the above error wasn't related to that I think. Thanks for the help!